# How to disable column / table sorting (initially enabled) in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

What is an API for that?

Use case why I need it:
While performing external sorting I'd like to disable sorting on table (because it will refresh content as many times as many times was clicked column header) or on specific column and to enable back on success or error.

Answer (score 5):

set

```
enableSorting: false
```

in your grid option

change same property dynamically should work.

Comment: I've tried to change it dynamically - grid still allows to click on row header to perfom sorting

Answer (score 0):

```
set enableSorting: false,
gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yeah, sorting still happens with these lines for me after an edit. Really bummed about it!